# Why is 1-Ethyl-1-methylcyclohexane achiral?

Tags: chirality

I was wondering why the 1-Ethyl-1-methylcyclohexane molecule is achiral.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself . Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange

Comment: Because of absence of chiral center* & a better reason, you can easily cut out plane of symmetry in this molecule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional groups are on the same carbon, so either configuration can be rotated into the other. If the functional groups were on different carbons, then depending on their relative locations the molecule could be chiral.

Comment: Second sentence is not correct.  Cis and trans 1-ethyl-4-methycyclohexane are achiral.

Comment: Should be OK now.

Comment: Oversight on my part, thank you for the correction!